# Difference between Authenticated Encryption Modes and Generic Composition Schemes

Tags: hash, cryptography, cryptographic-hash-function

i would like to ask about:

What is the difference between Authenticated Encryption Modes and Generic Composition Schemes in cryptography?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic Composition Scheme basically tells you take some proven cipher and some proven MAC function, use the cipher for encryption and the MAC for integrity in some way and hope for the best.
Authenticated encryption modes are basically the same thing, just some cipher with a MAC function, but usually those where checked and have provable security. Such as GCM is a combination of CTR mode with GMAC, or CCM that uses CTR mode with CBC-MAC. Or using AES-CBC with HMAC.